# Scale/shrink a widget and keeping the font sizes in propotion

Tags: flutter

I want to show a small version of my widget on the screen, and I'm hoping it doesn't need to create a separate widget.

Is there a widget that I can use to wrap my existing widget, which can scale or shrink my widget while keeping `font sizes`/images in proportion?

I've tried aspect ratio and `transform.scale` - both of these didn't scale the fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `transform.scale` and at the same time for the font resizing you can have two approaches:

1. you can use `AutoSizedText` ([link](https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text))

```
AutoSizeText(
      "yourText"
    ),
```

2. or you can wrap your text with `FittedBox`

```
FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, 
        child: Text('Hey this is my long text appbar title')
    ),
```

Comment: @user1012500 did my solution help you?

Comment: Hi thank you, that resolves my question and it works.